# Simple exercise on probability theory

Tags: probability

I have got a simple task on probability theory and not able to solve it correctly.

A student is able to solve 7 tasks out of 10. On the exam, he gets a sheet with 5 tasks randomly containing tasks out of those 10. He would pass the exam if he will solve at least 4 tasks. What is a probability that he will pass the exam?

My attempt is the following. The probability that the student will obtain not more than 1 unsolvable task is
$$
P = (A_{7}^{5}A_{3}^{0}+A_{7}^{4}A_{3}^{1})/A_{10}^{5},
$$
but not sure in the solution, since the naive total probability calculated in such a way is not equal to 1:
$$
P_{\text{full}} = (A_{7}^{5}A_{3}^{0}+A_{7}^{4}A_{3}^{1}+A_{7}^{3}A_{3}^{2}+A_{7}^{2}A_{3}^{3})/A_{10}^{5} \neq 1
$$

Comment: first, there is a typo question. Also, when you edit your question, please include your attempt as well.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh : I have added both the points you mentioned.

Comment: The second $A^1_3$ in the last formula should be $A^2_3$ I think. Weird notation though.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : thank you, I have corrected.

Comment: @JohnTaylor now the sum does sum to one.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : but I obtain $P_{\text{full}} = 1$ only when replacing $A_{x}^{y}$ by $C_{x}^{y}$, where $A_{x}^{y} = x!/y!$ and $C_{x}^{y} = x!/(y!(x-y)!)$. I do not understand what is a reason for this.

Comment: I assumed $A^y_x$ meant what you denoted by $C^y_x$, so $\binom{x}{y}$. But the order is irrelevant so we need unordered choices, not ordered ones.

Answer (score 2):

Your working is fine. Note that

$$\frac{\binom75 \cdot \binom30 +\binom74 \cdot \binom31 + \binom73 \cdot \binom32 + \binom72 \cdot \binom33 }{\binom{10}{5}}=1$$